# Unordered Lists: Limiting the number of List-items before starting a new column

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists, multiple-columns

My brain is fried so I apologize if this seems extremely simple:

I have an unordered list:

```
<ul class="activeList">
   <li class="item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="item">Item 2</li>
   <li class="item">Item 3</li>
   <li class="item">Item 4</li>
   <li class="item">Item 5</li>
   <li class="item">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

And all I'm trying to do is to get it to display vertically into two columns, but after Item 4, to start the second column. So it would look like this:

```
Item 1   |   Item 5
Item 2   |   Item 6
Item 3   |
Item 4   |
```

I've tried floats and columns in CSS, but the best I can get is this:

```
Item 1   |   Item 4
Item 2   |   Item 5
Item 3   |   Item 6
```

I'm looking to get it to cap the column at 4 then start the next column.
I'm hoping to find a CSS-only solution.

Comment: Let me guess, the height of an item is not fixed? :)

Comment: no, it is... and I JUST stumbled upon column-fill, and setting the li-height and ul-height so that the wrap occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I stumbled upon the simplest CSS-only answer almost immediately after I posted the question, so I'm going to share it with everyone:

the UL needs to have a fixed HEIGHT, PLUS the CSS rule column-fill: auto. Ensuring that the LI's have a fixed height (which can be modified), you can adjust the height of the LI's until the wrapping occurs where you need it, whether you want the wrap to occur after the fourth li, or any other li.

```css
.active-list {
     padding-left: 0;
    column-count: 2;
    column-fill: auto;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #595757;
    height: 245px;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="active-list">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="item">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by using flex-wrap and nth child. Take a look at the codepen, should be pretty self-explanatory. If not, let me know! The nice thing about this is it will work if you need more than just 2 columns.

See demo and [codepen](https://codepen.io/jowtow/pen/ErdBMx):

```css
.activeList{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

.item:nth-child(3n){
  page-break-after:always; 
  break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<ul class="activeList">
   <li class="item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="item">Item 2</li>
   <li class="item">Item 3</li>
   <li class="item">Item 4</li>
   <li class="item">Item 5</li>
   <li class="item">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think it's a chrome thing, I will fix it.

Comment: Ye you are right, it's definitely a chrome thing. Working for me in firefox. If you manage to fix it let me know, your answer looks like the best.

Comment: @JohnTownsend you don't  need *breaks* here. As OP says `height` of the container can be fixed, you can just *adjust* the `height` to get the desired layout. +1 to the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest approach imo is to use flexbox.
You have to breakdown your list in 2 parts: 1st part from elements 1 to 4 / 2nd part from element 5 to 6. Then wrap them into a display flex container.

That would do it, take a look at the snippet :)

```css
#container { /*The only CSS property you need*/
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"> <!--flex container-->
    <ul class="activeList-1-4"> <!--first list-->
        <li class="item">
            Item 1
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            Item 2
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            Item 3
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            Item 4
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="activeList-5-6"><!--second list-->
        <li class="item">
            Item 5
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            Item 6
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What about if you give a height of the container, here your container is 'activeList' and give your container 'display: inline-flex' and flex wrap for wrapping.
[demo](https://codepen.io/angryillusionist/pen/JxmBOj)

```
.activeList{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 72px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item{
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```